# Onclick Javascript Buttons with Lightning Experience

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lightning, validation, lightning-experience

Currently in classic view we are validating fields using onclick javascript button before calling visualforce page.Client wants to move to lightning experience but [lightning doesn't support onclick javascript button](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cGX8AAM).Any other ways to validate fields before calling visualforce page in lightning experience?

Comment: Any reason you can't create a component that exercises the validation ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create lightning components to do that. 
Here a good guide to replace onclick javascript buttons

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/09/take-the-first-steps-ways-you-can-replace-javascript-buttons.html